# JAVA JDBC SQL updating a new database based on the old database records

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection, informix

I am trying to write a runnable jar file that can be able to connect to 2 different databases informix old database and oracle new database. It should be able to update the new database(oracle) with the old database(informix) records.

I re-edit my java code I added separate methods for my select, update and connections I am not getting an error but its not updating my db. My select works but my update statement is not working. This is my result i get -  `SELECT profile_id, ingress_flag, egress_flag, ce_ingress_flag, ce_egress_flag from COS_PROFILE where profile_id = 102
profileid : 102
ingressflag : Y
egress_flag : Y
ceingressflag : Y
ceegressflag : Y
ResultSet not open, operation 'next' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is OFF`

I am not sure how can I fixed the `ResultSet not open, operation 'next' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is OFF`

```
public class TestConnection {

static ResultSet rs;

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception  {


    try{
        selectRecordsIcore();
        updateRecordIntoBids();
    }  catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public static void selectRecordsIcore() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    String selectTableSQL = "SELECT profile_id, ingress_flag, egress_flag, ce_ingress_flag, ce_egress_flag from COS_PROFILE";


    try {
        dbConnection = getInformixConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

         System.out.println(selectTableSQL);

        // execute select SQL stetement
         rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);

                while (rs.next()) {

                int profileid = rs.getInt("profile_id");
                String ingressflag = rs.getString("ingress_flag");
                String egress_flag = rs.getString("egress_flag");
                String ceingressflag = rs.getString("ce_ingress_flag");
                String ceegressflag = rs.getString("ce_egress_flag");

                System.out.println("profileid : " + profileid);
                System.out.println("ingressflag : " + ingressflag);
                System.out.println("egress_flag : " + egress_flag);
                System.out.println("ceingressflag : " + ceingressflag);
                System.out.println("ceegressflag : " + ceegressflag);


            }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}


private static void updateRecordIntoBids() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ArrayList<TempStorageRecords>  updateSQL = new  ArrayList<TempStorageRecords>();

    while (rs.next()) {

        int profileid = rs.getInt("profile_id");
        String ingressflag = rs.getString("ingress_flag");
        String egress_flag = rs.getString("egress_flag");
        String ceingressflag = rs.getString("ce_ingress_flag");
        String ceegressflag = rs.getString("ce_egress_flag");



            String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE traffic_profile SET ingress_flag  = " +  ingressflag
                 + " ,egress_flag = " + egress_flag
                 + " ,ce_ingress_flag = " + ceingressflag
                 + " ,ce_egress_flag = " + ceegressflag 
                 + " WHERE profile_id = " + profileid +  ";";

            try {
                dbConnection = getOracleConnection();
                statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

                System.out.println("updateTableSQL 1 :" + updateTableSQL);

                // execute update SQL stetement
                statement.execute(updateTableSQL);

                System.out.println("updateTableSQL 2: " + updateTableSQL);

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            } finally {

                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }

                if (dbConnection != null) {
                    dbConnection.close();
                }

            }   
    }

   }





public static Connection getOracleConnection() throws SQLException {
String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle_host:1521:BIDS";
String username = "username";
String password = "password";
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} // load Oracle driver
Connection dbConnection = null;

try {

    Class.forName(driver);

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}

try {

    dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            url, username,password);
    return dbConnection;

} catch (SQLException e) {

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}

return dbConnection;


 }

public static Connection getInformixConnection() throws SQLException {
    String driver = "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:informix-sqli://informix_host:1615/icore:INFORMIXSERVER=icit";
    String username = "user";
    String password = "pass";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } // load Informix driver
    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(driver);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                url, username,password);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    return dbConnection;
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't do it like this. You will need two statements, one for each db and program the transfer of data yourself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel -- To be fair, you can access two different data sources in a single query if you set up federation, such as Oracle Transparent Gateway or InfoSphere Federation Server.

Comment: @mustaccio True, but in that case it wouldn't be really JDBC related, but more related to the exact syntax of the system used. The code shows two different connections leading me to assume a pure JDBC solution.

Comment: is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there is. Read the data from one database and store it to the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first try to export data from source database into text file.

Your code uses hard coded column names, but I think it could read table names to export from some config file and column names from metadata from `SELECT * FROM [table_name]`. In JDBC there is `getMetaData()` for RecordSet. Use it.

When you export data into text files without problems you can do the next step: import such data directly from the source database to the destination database.

For destination database create `prepareStatement` with:

```
'INSERT INTO ' + table_name_dest + ' (' + column_names +') VALUES ('+ question_marks + ')'
```

(there *question_marks* are '?' chars which maps to columns).

Then for each record from source table and for each record (row) do:

```
insert_stmt.setObject(i, rs_in.getObject(i))
```

For big tables you can also use `setFetchSize()` and `addBatch()/executeBatch()`